# grid Adapter inside a fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-asynctask

im trying to get the output frm a async class and use in a grid view in side a fragment 
im sure that my inputs are correct

```
 public void processFinish(movieList output) {
        String[] movieId=output.getMovieId();
        String[] movieImg=output.getMovieId();
        boolean response=output.getStatus();
        if(response==true){
            GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView_cover);
            MovieAdapter = new movieGridAdapter(getActivity(), movieImg);
            gridView.setAdapter(MovieAdapter);
}
```

GridAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(view==null){
            imageView= new ImageView(mContext);
            // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        }
        else
        {
            imageView=(ImageView) view;

        }

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(image_base_url+imgs[position]).into(imageView);
        //Log.v(movieGridAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+imgs[position]);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_ADAPTER_LAYOUT, null);
            imageView= new ImageView(mContext);
            // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
```

You are not inflating the layout for your gridview, thus you cannot see anything!